# How should I format my data prior realizing this plot?

Tags: r, plot

I want to plot three graphs in one plot: upper quartile, median, and lower quartile over time.

Right now I have the data in this format:

```
t_1 x_1 x_2 ... x_n
t_2 x_1 x_2 ... x_n
... ... ... ... ...
t_m x_1 x_2 ... x_n
```

That is, n observations at m points in time.

Is there an input format better suited for realizing this task in R?

As my experience with R is very limited I'd like to avoid having to transform the data in R. I collect it from a couple of different files, so I'm pretty flexible when it comes to preprocessing the data.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Seems to me that you want your data to look like:

```
t   lq   med   uq
1   ..    ..   ..
2   ..    ..   ..
3   ..    ..   ..
4   ..    ..   ..
```

Therefore, the format you have it in seems to be just fine.  Once it's in R, you can use apply to produce the right three columns:

```
res.df <- data.frame(t(apply(my.data.frame[,2:ncol(my.data.frame)], 1, quantile,probs=c(.25,.5,.75))))
res.df$t <- my.data.frame[,1]

res.df
         X25.        X50.        X75.   t
1 0.028624900 0.031074701 0.037136365 200
2 0.016687651 0.021395864 0.025269186 300
3 0.010939904 0.014344707 0.016897053 400
4 0.007891868 0.009855513 0.011671379 500
5 0.006553960 0.008057315 0.009885929 600
6 0.005831083 0.006755695 0.008090646 700
```

Then just plot.

```
# Sample data
t=seq(33)
lq=runif(33)
med = lq+runif(33)*2
res.df <- data.frame( t=t, lq=lq, med = med, uq=med+runif(33)*2 )
colnames(res.df) <- c("t","lq","med","uq")

# Base graphics
plot(lq~t,data=res.df,type="l",col="springgreen",ylim=range(c(lq,uq)))
lines(med~t,data=res.df,col="steelblue")
lines(uq~t,data=res.df,col="springgreen")
```

[image: base graphics]

```
# ggplot2
res.df <- melt(res.df,id.vars="t")
library(ggplot2)
p <- ggplot(res.df, aes(y=value,x=t,colour=variable) )
p + geom_line()
```

[image: ggplot2 graphics]

Comment: +1 but fivenum() might be more succinct and includes the median.

Comment: Good point, but he only wants the middle three so either have to subset it as a generic function in the apply or in the data.frame afterwards (or just ignore the extra columns when plotting).

Comment: I read the data in via read.table() and then called your apply(). However, this produced a rather weird looking data set ([,1] with values for 25%, 50%, 75%) rather than what you outlined above. Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Made the example sketch more explicit.  Did that fix it?  If not, please paste the results of `dput(my.data.frame)` so we have some sample data to work with.  If you dataset is huge, try  `dput(head(my.data.frame))`.  Thanks.

Comment: htorque, the 25th percentile (25%) is the lower quartile, and so on. For plotting, try `matplot` on the transpose of the result matrix.

Comment: @gsk3 http://paste.ubuntu.com/653341 I guess the second line won't work without some kind of header in the original file?

Comment: @gsk3 - I think maybe the confusion is the lack of a transpose on your results? That's a bit of a 'gotcha' when using `apply`.

Comment: @joran: Once I had example data, the need for transpose became apparent.  Nice job picking it up without having it in front of you!

Comment: @htorque: Yup, I was expecting the columns to be named as in the example.  Made it generic, which I like less since it depends on order not naming, but it works for this purpose.

Comment: Sure.  `apply` and its relatives `sapply` `lapply` `mapply` etc. are very R-like ways of doing things.  It's worth reading up on how they work and playing around with them until they make sense, as it'll save you tons of frustration and ugly code :-)

Comment: @gsk3: Yeah, it seems that you can't do simple thing in R without studying. Hard. On the other hand: it's really worth it! :)

Comment: @htorque: Focus on learning a few key packages well.  `plyr` is a good place to start for data manipulation, as are the base functions.  And then for plots either `lattice` or `ggplot2`.

Comment: But if you want to use ggplot2 (or pretty much anything other than matplot), this data format won't work.  You'll want to melt it first.

Comment: @hadley: You are, of course, quite correct for one of the higher-order plotting tools.  I was thinking base graphics which colored by answer.  Added solutions to both to answer.